# Broken SSH to recover

Tags: linux, ssh

I've been messing up my ssh as trying to add a new user. Now I can not access server Via ssh I have access to Parallel is there a hope to recover ssh connection?

```
ssh -v -v -v root@mydomm.com
```

drops

```
Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
```

History before disaster

```
useradd myname
passwd myname
```

than edited

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

added

```
AllowUsers myname
```

restarted

```
service ssh restart
```

after all of this exit
and trying to log in but even root is not working now

Making a bit of research after recovery how to add a new ssh users I found it that doesn't needs any editing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` just simply add a new user `adduser youusername` and reload `ssh service ssh reload`

Comment: It depends on whatever you did to mess it up.  Did you make a backup before you made any changes?  Do you keep a log of what you did?

Comment: logs I can access backup this time I did not made

Comment: I don't mean can you get to the system logs, I mean do you have notes about exactly what you were doing?  Like a console history?  You could have done dozens of things to break your system.  If you can't tell us what you did, then telling you how to fix it will have to be random guesses...

Comment: okay I will try to document

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set `AllowUsers myname` in your configuration. This means that *only* `myname` can log in to the server with ssh. Not even `root` can log in since it is not named in `AllowUsers`.

To resolve the issue, login and fix or remove the `AllowUsers` directive.

Comment: I got it to work resetting all changes in /etc/ssh/sshd_config via Parallel. Anyway would be good to know how to add properly a new ssh user